# Magento 2.4.3 Products not showing up in order confirmation mail

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2, email-templates

I am trying to make my email templates work.

I have the following scenario:

I have a custom theme that does not influence the standard mail templates.
The problem persists, even when I am activating the Magento Luma theme.

The Problem:

No Products are showing up inside the order confirmation mail.

To display products, inside the mail, following snipped is needed:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}
```

My Magento version is 2.4.3; I upgraded from version 2.4.1 where the problem was the same. So updating didn't help.

Comment: maybe a "" would do the job around $order_id

Comment: Then its just parse it as an String

Comment: Please try to wrap $order_id with double quotes , and tell us what happenes

Comment: I tried. It doesnt work.

Comment: Does it work in a standard Magento installation?

Comment: @NicolaiKamphenkel Hi, were you able to get it solved? I am too having this problem with the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the legacy tag inside the database it should behave differently and should work.

Comment: This field was gone at version 2.4.3 . In version 2.4.1 ist just throw an error.